# select Two Dates from calendar tjeervurig

Tags: ios, objective-c

i use this calendar https://github.com/TjeerdVurig/Vurig-Calendar

how can i select two dates and perform action after select these Two dates and make all the dates between these Two Dates Selected Highlighted blue

As Example i select 1 - 1/3/2013
                    2 - 5/3/2013

After I click On The Two Dates It highlight all the dates in between {1,2,3,4,5}/3/2013 with blue color and Then Perform An Action

Comment: Have you asked the author?

Comment: the author not answer

Comment: I'm guessing you'd have to modify the code, if there is no API to do this, and the existing API is at too high of a level to let you highlight multiple dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    id markedDateObj1 = [self.markedDates objectAtIndex:1];
    NSDate *date1 = (NSDate *)markedDateObj1;
    id markedDateObj0 = [self.markedDates objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDate *date0 = (NSDate *)markedDateObj0;
    if ([date0 day]-1 && i==[date0 day]-1) {
        CGRect rectangleGrid = CGRectMake(targetX,targetY,kVRGCalendarViewDayWidth+2,kVRGCalendarViewDayHeight+2);
        CGContextAddRect(context, rectangleGrid);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"0x006dbc"].CGColor);
        CGContextFillPath(context);

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,
                                       [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    }
    if ([date1 day]-1 && i==[date1 day]-1) {
        CGRect rectangleGrid = CGRectMake(targetX,targetY,kVRGCalendarViewDayWidth+2,kVRGCalendarViewDayHeight+2);
        CGContextAddRect(context, rectangleGrid);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"0x006dbc"].CGColor);
        CGContextFillPath(context);

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,
                                       [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    }
    for (int ai=[date0 day]; ai<[date1 day]-1; ai++) {

        if (ai && i==ai) {
            CGRect rectangleGrid = CGRectMake(targetX,targetY,kVRGCalendarViewDayWidth+2,kVRGCalendarViewDayHeight+2);
            CGContextAddRect(context, rectangleGrid);
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"0x0095FF"].CGColor);
            CGContextFillPath(context);

            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,
                                           [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
        }
    }
```